# Python:merge columns of data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

How can I merge two dataframe based on a if condition?

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'text':['ASX-112','YTR-789','ASX-124','UYT-908','TYE=456','ERW-234'],
'code':['red','red','red','blue','blue','blue'],'id':[2,2,2,3,3,3]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'grade':['a','b','c','d'],'code':['red','blue','blue','blue'],'id':[2,3,3,3]})
```

df1:

```py
      text  code  id
0  ASX-112   red   2
1  YTR-789   red   2
2  ASX-124   red   2
3  UYT-908  blue   3
4  TYE=456  blue   3
5  ERW-234  blue   3
```

df2:

```py
  grade  code  id
0     a   red   2
1     b  blue   3
2     c  blue   3
3     d  blue   3
```

I need the result in the form like it should be able to merge the dataframes into one based on the color and id and should result like below:

[image]

I have written below code to merge it but I get some different result:

```
df5 = pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,on='page')
```

Comment: What is the `if` condition you're basing your merge on? What is the logic behind which of the three blue grades are assigned?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This gets the desired result, but may not generalize to your actual use-case:

```py
>>> df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["code", "id"])
>>> df
       text  code  id grade
0   ASX-112   red   2     a
1   YTR-789   red   2     a
2   ASX-124   red   2     a
3   UYT-908  blue   3     b
4   UYT-908  blue   3     c
5   UYT-908  blue   3     d
6   TYE=456  blue   3     b
7   TYE=456  blue   3     c
8   TYE=456  blue   3     d
9   ERW-234  blue   3     b
10  ERW-234  blue   3     c
11  ERW-234  blue   3     d
```

Then grab all the `a` grades, and concatenate with every 4th row from non-`a` grades:

```py
>>> mask = df["grade"] == "a"
>>> pd.concat([df[mask], df[~mask].iloc[::4]]).reset_index(drop=True)
      text  code  id grade
0  ASX-112   red   2     a
1  YTR-789   red   2     a
2  ASX-124   red   2     a
3  UYT-908  blue   3     b
4  TYE=456  blue   3     c
5  ERW-234  blue   3     d
```